# Django: WARNING - Method Not Allowed (POST)

Tags: python, django, django-views

I know what above error means. Seems I can't handle form when it is posted. I can do it in function based views, but in class based views I am tad lost.

I am creating a comment app and here is `forms.py` content in `comment` app:

```
class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    content_type = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)
    object_id = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)
    body = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

then in `DetailView` of the blog app, I handled it this way:

```
class BlogDetail(DetailView):
    model = Blog
    template_name = 'blogs/blog_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'blog'

    def get_object(self):
        blog_slug = self.kwargs.get('blog_slug')
        return get_object_or_404(Blog, slug=blog_slug)

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = self.get_object()
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['comments'] = Comment.objects.filter_by_instance(obj)

        """ comment form """
        initial_data = {
            'content_type': obj.get_content_type,
            'object_id': obj.id
        }
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            form = CommentForm(self.request.POST, initial=initial_data)
            if form.is_valid():
                c_type = form.cleaned_data.get('content_type')
                content_type = ContentType.objects.get(model=c_type)
                object_id = form.cleaned_data.get('object_id')
                body = form.cleaned_data.get('body')
                new_comment, created = Comment.objects.get_or_create(
                    user=self.request.user,
                    content_type=content_type,
                    object_id=object_id,
                    body=body
                )
        else: 
            form = CommentForm(initial=initial_data)

        context['comment_form'] = form

        return context
```

albeit I passsed `form = CommentForm(self.request.POST, initial=initial_data)` but there sounds something is going wrong, Can anyone help? Thank you

edited:

```
class BlogDetail(DetailView, FormView):
    model = Blog
    template_name = 'blogs/blog_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'blog'
    form_class = CommentForm

    def get_object(self):
        blog_slug = self.kwargs.get('blog_slug')
        return get_object_or_404(Blog, slug=blog_slug)

    def get_initial(self):
        obj = self.get_object()
        return {
            'content_type': obj.get_content_type,
            'object_id': obj.id
        }

    def form_valid(self, form):
        c_type = form.cleaned_data.get('content_type')
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get(model=c_type)
        object_id = form.cleaned_data.get('object_id')
        body = form.cleaned_data.get('body')

        Comment.objects.create(
            user=self.request.user,
            content_type=content_type,
            object_id=object_id,
            body=body
        )
```

edit 2:

Can anyone spot the error with this approach:

```
class BlogDetail(DetailView):
    model = Blog
    template_name = 'blogs/blog_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'blog'
    form_class = CommentForm

    def get_object(self):
        blog_slug = self.kwargs.get('blog_slug')
        return get_object_or_404(Blog, slug=blog_slug)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = self.get_object()

        initial_data = {
            'content_type': obj.get_content_type,
            'object_id': obj.id
        }
        print("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", obj.get_content_type)
        form = self.form_class(initial=initial_data)

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            c_type = form.cleaned_data.get('content_type')
            content_type_2 = ContentType.objects.get(model=c_type)
            object_id = form.cleaned_data.get('object_id')
            body = form.cleaned_data.get('body')

            Comment.objects.create(
                user=request.user,
                content_type=content_type_2,
                object_id=object_id,
                body=body,
            )

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

Comment: Never combine two views. If you want to add form support to a detail view, add FormMixin, not FormView. On second thought, you don't need detail view. You can solve the rendering of the object by calling get_object() in get_context_data...

Comment: please provide an answer, or see my second approach, why it doesn't work in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Posts are handled by the `post` method of the class-based view:

```
class BlogDetail(DetailView):
    # ...
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # all your form processing
```

Django ships with several views, that already provide various hooks into the form handling process, e.g.  [`FormView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#formview), that you could leverage instead:

```
class BlogDetail(DetailView, FormView):
    form_class = CommentForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        c_type = form.cleaned_data.get('content_type')
        # ...

    def get_initial(self):
        obj = self.get_object()
        return {
            'content_type': obj.get_content_type,
            'object_id': obj.id
        }

    # ....
```

By default, the form is passed as `"form"` into the context.

Comment: Thank you for help, please see the editted question. I am missing something

Answer (score 0):

To allow post requests to your view, write a function `def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs)` which will receive the post request. If you want to handle this as you would handle get, redirect it to the get function

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this, but it doesnt work in my case. Can you please look at my question. I edited and used the approach you said here.

Comment: `ContentType matching query does not exist` and did you see edited? I used get and post methods in class based views

Comment: Shouldn't you call `obj.get_content_type` as `obj.get_content_type()`?

Comment: it says `'ContentType' object is not callable`. I thought maybe it has to do something with the database. I deleted database and remade, same results

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `DetailView`. You can simply use CreateView. I think you have everything overridden correctly to be able to ditch DetailView, except maybe get_form_kwargs().

However...

I usually approach this differently, cause it's confusing and very hacky. Instead, you add the form via get_context_data() to the DetailView and then in the template post to `/blog/{id}/comment/create`, where you have the CreateView. That makes things a lot simpler.

Comment: I need `DetailView` to show the details of blog, so I have to keep it and I want to learn without having to post to a comment `CreateView` how I can do it within one simple `DetailView` class. Can you please see my second edited question. I used `post` method there to handle this situation. thank you for help